# How can I speed up my conversion of pandas dataframe column types?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I am developing a python module that allows users to read a little over 1M rows x 372 columns into memory from parquet files for folks to perform analysis on like this:

```
data = pandas.read_parquet(url1 + str(year) + url2, columns=columns, engine='fastparquet')
```

I'm trying to proactively cut down on the data size by converting some of the data types, e.g. object to category, int64 to int32 etc, by doing the following:

```
for column in test.select_dtypes(include=['object']):
    
    if len(test[column].unique()) < 100:
        test[column] = test[column].astype('category')
        
for column in test.select_dtypes(include=['int64']):
    
    test[column] = test[column].astype('int32')

for column in test.select_dtypes(include=['float64']):
    
    test[column] = test[column].astype('float32')
```

This works and reduces the data size by ~50%, but it's slow (the full conversion takes ~3 min compared to just 1 min to do the initial data import). Is there another method to make this run faster? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of converting using pandas methods try with numpy arrays which is much faster. For example:

```
test[column] = np.array(test[column], dtype=np.float32)
```

Check for different data types from numpy documentations:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, that cut run time 50%!

Answer (score 0):

For me, dropping the column before setting it it significantly sped up the time, for example:

```
column_names = newShortEntries.select_dtypes(include=[object]).columns
temp =  newShortEntries[column_names].astype(bool) #np.array(newShortEntries[column_names], dtype=np.bool_)
newShortEntries = newShortEntries.drop(columns=column_names)
newShortEntries[column_names] = temp
```